# How to load a file that I'll use as class attributes where the order of these attributes can change

Tags: python

I have a .csv file that I'm trying to load, and it has information related to football players: An example of the first 3 lines could be:

```
name,position,shooting,dribbling
Cristiano Ronaldo,forward,95,88
Lionel Messi,winger,85,92
Eden Hazard,winger,92,95
```

I also have the class player:

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, position, shooting, dribbling):
        self.name = name
        self.position = position
        self.dribbling = dribbling
        self.shooting = shooting
```

I need to load the data from the .csv file to then use it with the class Player. The problem that I have is that sometimes the order of the data can be changed, so for example the first 2 lines of the file could look like this instead of like above:

```
position,shooting,name,dribbling
forward,95,Cristiano Ronaldo,88
...
```

What would be an efficient way of loading the data correctly everytime?

Comment: 1. Look up how to load csv files. It will load your result as list of dictionaries. 2. Read about dict unpacking. 3. `Player(**{"name":"any order", "dribbling":"will work", "shooting":"because", "position":"arguments are named"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As h4z3 suggested in the comment, dict unpacking is very good in these cases. And you can combine it with `csv` module.

First let's put it in 2 files `meh.csv` and `meh2.csv`:

```
import csv
list_of_players = []    
with open('meh.csv', 'r') as file:
       reader = csv.DictReader(file)
       for line in reader: 
          list_of_players += [Player(**line)]
with open('meh2.csv', 'r') as file:
       reader = csv.DictReader(file)
       for line in reader: 
          list_of_players += [Player(**line)]
```

Result:

```
list_of_players[0].name
'Cristiano Ronaldo'
list_of_players[-1].name
'Cristiano Ronaldo'
list_of_players[-2].name
'Eden Hazard'
```

I used a list to store object, but you are obviously free to pack them as you want.